# How to convert object to list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I need to convert this object into list in expressJS view (using EJS):

```
{https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12Xa4ipGWBuNjy0Fbq6z4sXXa3/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10xfciv9TBuNjy1zbq6xpepXaG/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB13AHqcfiSBuNkSnhJq6zDcpXav/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg}
```

I've tried :

```
<% const xx = result.data[0].galleryimages.replace('{',"['").replace('}',"']").split(',') %>



        <% for (let j=0; j<xx.length; j++) { %>
           <%= xx[j]%>

        <% } %>
```

but it returns :

```
['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12Xa4ipGWBuNjy0Fbq6z4sXXa3/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10xfciv9TBuNjy1zbq6xpepXaG/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB13AHqcfiSBuNkSnhJq6zDcpXav/Mickey-Mouse-Microwave-Glove-Potholder-Bakeware-Blue-and-White-100-Cotton-Oven-Mitts-and-Potholder-mat.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is not an object, it's a string - try:

```
const xx = result.data[0].galleryimages.replace(/[{}]/, '').split(',')
```

Comment: I've changed it into a list now (https://hastebin.com/ilirufahag.json) , how do I iterate those values in img tag ? @ic3b3rg

Comment: @BizaireAdmin please update question accordingly. Also, what is wrong with ic3b3rg answer?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

```
<% let xx = result.data[0].galleryimages.slice(1,-1).split(",") %> 
        <% for (let j=0; j<xx.length; j++) { %>
            <% let ha = xx[j].slice(1,-1); %>
           <img src=<%= ha.replace("'","") %> width="10%"/>
        <% } %>
```